# how can I decide whether to show a virtual keyboard in Windows?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, touch

how can I automatically decide whether to show a virtual keyboard in Windows?

We're adding support for gestures and a virtual keyboard in our application but don't want to see the virtual keyboard when I have a real keyboard attached...

Thank you!

Update:  RRUZ (who doesn't have a win8 tablet) had a helpful suggestion but it didn't work because win8 tablet does not behave as expected.

```
To get the number of keyboards present in the system you can use the Win32_Keyboard WMI class.

Try this sample

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  ComObj,
  Variants;

function  GetKeyboardCount : integer;
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;
begin;
  Result:=0;
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer('localhost', 'root\CIMV2', '', '');
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT DeviceID FROM Win32_Keyboard','WQL', $00000020);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  while oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 do
  begin
    Inc(Result);
    FWbemObject:=Unassigned;
  end;
end;

begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      Writeln(Format('Keyboards %d', [GetKeyboardCount]));
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:EOleException do
        Writeln(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode]));
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;
end.
```

In my experience this won't help in the real world: On my Win8 tablet Device Manager reports a PS/2 keyboard(!!), so functions like this will never tell you there's no keyboard. – Giel 9 hours ago

Comment: Are you asking how to detect if there's a keyboard device connected to the machine (to determine a touch device without a connected keyboard) ?

Comment: You could set a double click inside the `TEdit` as a trigger to show the virtuak keyboard, and advice users that they can do that.

Comment: @TLama: yes.  

EASI: the virtual kyd that appears with the touch support in delphi is not good enough.  we tried to use it first.